# Piecewise function, derivative problem

Tags: calculus

Let $$f(x)=\begin{cases}x^3, & x<1;\\ax^2+bx+c, & x\geq 1.\end{cases}$$ Find $a$ and $b$ so that $f''(1)$ exists

Can $a$ and $b$ be any number because the second derivative of a quadratic is a constant?
If not, can someone help me on how I can find those values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since we want the function value to track $x^3$ at $x=1$, we can find three equations to solve for the unknowns.

- Equation 1: Second Derivative: $f''(1) = 2a = 6 \rightarrow a = 3$
- Equation 2: First Derivative: $f'(1) = 2a + b = 3 \rightarrow b = -3$
- Equation 3: Function Value: $f(1) = a + b + c = 1 \rightarrow c = 1$

You can validate continuity of this function at $x=1$.

Comment: @EagleTamer: For $x<1$, we have $f''(x) = 6$ and at $x=1$, we have $f''(1)=6$. Same for the first derivative, we have $f'(x) = 3x^2$ and at $x=1$, we get $f'(1) = 3$. In the last case we evaluate $x^3$ at $x=1$. We are using both values of the piecewise function since we want them to be equal at $x=1$, including their first and second derivative. Clear?

Answer (score 1):

Solve the linear system

$$\begin{array}{rcll}
x^3 &=& a\cdot x^2+b\cdot x+c \\
3\cdot x^2 &=& 2a\cdot x+b \\
6\cdot x &=& 2a
\end{array}$$

where $x=1$